# SDL C++ Issues (Window in wait status)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I am working with SDL and OpenGL, I create the SDL_Surface and SDL_SetVideoMode:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

const SDL_VideoInfo * dinfo = SDL_GetVideoInfo();

// Setup the surface of SDL
if(configurer::fullscreened){
    data::Wnd_Surface = SDL_SetVideoMode(configurer::window_width,configurer::window_height,dinfo->vfmt->BitsPerPixel,SDL_FULLSCREEN | SDL_OPENGL);
}else{
    data::Wnd_Surface = SDL_SetVideoMode(configurer::window_width,configurer::window_height,16,SDL_OPENGL);
}
if(data::Wnd_Surface==0){
    return -1;
}

SDL_WM_SetCaption("Test", "Test");

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

// Initialize GLEW
if(glewInit()!=0){
    cout << "Failed to start glew";
    return -1;
}
```

I init it in my main function, then I have the following (on the main function):

```
while(!data::terminate){
    AscMainLoop();
    SDL_Delay(80);
}
return 0;
```

Everything fine. My AscMainLoop function:

```
int timerelapse = SDL_GetTicks();
//Check for key events
    /* BLA BLA BLA *(
AscUpdateComponents(); // Update matrixes and bla bla bla...
AscRender();// Paint

// Fps Counter Update
    /* BLA BLA BLA */

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();// Swap the buffers of our screen
```

Ok, I am having an issue, I run the application, but the screen does not answer, I think the problem is the while loop on the main.
The window opens, but I can't drag it, resize it, it's like a wait status on the window (With the funny "please wait" cursor of windows 7) activates.
I already tried to put the main loop in a thread. I don't know what's happening...

Edit: It's like a freez status caused by the loop at the main function

Comment: Why are you calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` *after* `SDL_SetVideoMode()`?

Comment: I already fixed that, the problem stills there.

Comment: are you sure your "Check for key events" part isn't an infinite loop?

Comment: Actually I wrote wrong the code in the example, it's /* BLA BLA BLA */ hehe, that code is the AscMainLoop functions, is called in a while loop on the main, yes an infinite loop because it needs to be updating the SDL Surface (SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()) and drawing the objects with openGL. It's supposed to be an infinite loop, Like i said, i already tried in a thread...

Comment: You might want to teach yourself to use a debugger.

Comment: It's a freeze status, not an exception... The debugger does not says me anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to process your `SDL_Event`s either in your `while` or in your `AscMainLoop` by doing something like:

```
SDL_Event Event;

while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
{
    // Later, you'll be adding your code that handles keyboard / mouse input here
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know that, is that really necessary? Why?

Comment: While not documented, I assume on Windows it's also acting as a `WndProc` that processes messages for your window

Comment: That's the spirit!  Make something great! Feel free to ask if you have any more questions

Comment: fascinatingly (at least in windows) , you can actually have SDL_PollEvent in a separate thread, as long as that thread was the thread to initially call SDL_Init.  FWIW.